# Forwarding SMS messages to multiple phone #'s on Twilio

Tags: twilio

I currently use SMS forwarding to one number for multiple applications -- it keeps my SMS inbox nice and tidy -- love it.

However, we're using multiple SMS alert services and I'd like to forward them off to my team so we all get the alert. My coding skills aren't very strong, so I'm struggling here to understand what I can do to make this work.  So long story short, an SMS message comes in and is forwarded off immediately to multiple numbers.

Here's the code I use for forwarding to one number. What can I do to forward to multiple numbers?

```
> [root@centos64 html]# more fwdsms.php 
> <?php 
> header('Content-Type: text/html'); 
> ?> 
> <Response>   
>    <Message to="<?=$_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']?>">
> <?=htmlspecialchars(substr($_REQUEST['From'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 1600))?>   
> </Message> 
> </Response> 
> [root@centos64 html]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list of numbers to forward to is not crazy big, easiest in this case would probably be to just add multiple [`<Message>` verbs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) to your script.

```
<Message to="RECIPIENT1">
<?=htmlspecialchars(substr($_REQUEST['From'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 1600))?>   
</Message>
<Message to="RECIPIENT2">
<?=htmlspecialchars(substr($_REQUEST['From'] . ": " . $_REQUEST['Body'], 0, 1600))?>   
</Message>
```

To clean it up a bit you could store your `$_REQUEST` info in a `$message` variable and then do something like:

```
<Message to="RECIPIENT1"> <?php echo $message; ?></Message>
<Message to="RECIPIENT2"> <?php echo $message; ?></Message>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you're up and running.